# Convert specific date format to the calendar format

Tags: jquery

I have got a date in this format as a variable: `Friday, August 5th 2016, 09:00` and need to convert it to this format `2016,8,5,09,00,0,0,0` for my calendar file. Is there any simple way of doing it with jQuery? I have tried:

```
var oldDate = "Friday, August 5th 2016, 09:00";
var newDate = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd,HH,mm,0,0,0);
```

It didn't help. I really appreciate your time on sorting this out for me.

Comment: You need to make the date format in the string match one of the formats that a JS `Date()` object accepts, see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Description) on MDN for more info. To do that would depend on how you generate the date string.

Comment: Where does this date come from in the first place?

Comment: It is coming from the server as a part of json string @putvande

Comment: Does the date give any information about the Timezone, Daylight savings or even AM/PM?

Comment: Hi @CasparKleijne Timezone, Daylight savings not important, just time format is 24h.

Comment: Can you not convert it on the server? It would work if it came back as `"Friday, August 5 2016"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your date format is wrong.  The `th` is throwing javascript off when it tries to parse it.  You might want to consider changing the format that gets saved out to the server.  For this demo, I've just written a regular expression to parse it out.  After that it's pretty easy to get it to the right format.

```js
var oldDate = new Date("Friday, August 5th 2016, 09:00".replace(/(\d)+(st|nd|rd|th)/g, '$1'));
var newDate = [
  oldDate.getFullYear(),
  oldDate.getMonth() + 1,
  oldDate.getDate(),
  ('0' + oldDate.getHours()).slice(-2),
  ('0' + oldDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
  0,
  0,
  0
];
var formattedDate = newDate.join(',');
document.write(formattedDate);
```

Comment: a good one, one thing you are missing here i belief, i.e, if hour, min and sec are of 2 digit number, then it would be 020 or 059!!

Comment: @ameenulla0007 `.slice(-2)` works from the right going left and returns only the first two characters.  In combination with the `0` concatenation, it formats `9` as `09` and `23` as `23`.

Comment: oh that's great! i knew use of `slice`, thought like, if the input is `029` it would be `02`. :) over-all a good one, but thanks for the info.

Comment: @ameenulla0007 Yeah, slice with a negative value wraps around to the end and works backwards.  It comes in pretty handy for this.